# Time series in Hilbert spaces and expectation of a projection

Tags: probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, conditional-expectation, projection, time-series

Let $X_{t}$ be a stochastic process. For the realizations or random variables the natural metric is the standard deviation and the covariance as the inner product. For simplicity sake, lets assume that $\mathbb{E}X_{t}=0$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_{t}X_{t-j})= \sigma(j)$. One can generate a Hilbert space $H_{t}$ around the sequence of the realizations till period t of such stochastic process i.e. by taking the elements, linear combinations of these as well as the linear combinations of the limits, etc.

By the Hilbert Space Decomposition Theorem:

Let $H_{t} = H_{t-1}\otimes Ct$

where $Ct$ is another Hilbert space orthogonal to $H_{t-1}$. Its dimension is either zero or 1. In the case its zero, then $x_{t} \in H_{t-1}$.

How can I show that

$$\mathbb{V}(x_{t} - \mathbb{P}(x_{t}|H_{t-1}))= 0 $$? where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes projection of $x_{t}$ into $H_{t-1}$.

My approach was the following:

$$\mathbb{E}((x_{t} - \mathbb{P}(x_{t}|H_{t-1} ) - \mathbb{E}(x_{t} - \mathbb{P}(x_{t}|H_{t-1}))^{2}) $$

$$=\mathbb{E}((x_{t} - \mathbb{P}(x_{t}|H_{t-1} ) + \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{P}(x_{t}|H_{t-1}))^{2}) $$ ... by linearity of expectation and the assumption that $\mathbb{E}X_{t}=0$

How should I understand the expectation of a projection to get things to cancel out?

Comment: The variance need not be zero. For instance, consider the linear dynamics $X_t = \sqrt{\alpha} X_{t-1} + \sqrt{1-\alpha} W_t$, where $W_t$ is iid standard Gaussian noise. Due to the noise in the dynamics, which the projection (which amounts to a conditional expectation given the history) can't capture, the variance of $X_t$ minus the projection must be nonzero. Formally, the projection of $X_t$ onto the Hilbert space $L_2(\sigma(X_1^{t-1}))$ is $\alpha X_{t-1},$ which gives the variance $(1-\alpha) \mathbb{E}[w_t^2] = 1-\alpha$.

Comment: Moreover, the random variables with zero variance are the constants. What you are saying amounts to saying that conditional expectations capture all the information in the variable being conditioned, which is not true.